# How to load a UIImage from file without caching in Monotouch?

Tags: ios, uikit, xamarin.ios, uiimage

If I look at the discussion here:
http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/UIImageView-td4303177.html

Both, `UIImage.FromFile()` and `UIImage.FromFileUncached()` map to `imageWithContentsOfFile:` and are not supposed to cache, however my experience is different and I'm pretty sure that UIImage.FromFile() caches (from what I see in Instruments).

The documentation here (http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/Working_with_Images) states that `UIImage.FromBundle()` does cache, but `UIImage.FromFile()` does not. Is that still true? Or is there maybe some magic that `FromFile()` caches if the image is inside the app bundle?

Can somebody please make clear what is the correct way to:

- Load a UIImage with caching?
- Load a UIImage without caching ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UIImage.FromFile` and `UIImage.FromFileUncached` are **identical**. They both call the same `imageWithContentsOfFile:` selector.

Xamarin's documentation on [`FromFileUncached`](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M:MonoTouch.UIKit.UIImage.FromFileUncached%28System.String%29) explain why this was done.

> Alias to FromFile, merely with a more explicit name to draw attention to the cache-less nature of this call compared to FromBundle.

Historically the original API for this selector was named `FromFileUncached`, while the old  `FromFile` method was mapped to `imageNamed:` - but it turned out this was a mistake since the later selector means from the bundle.

A new `FromBundle` methods was added and, not to break the API, `FromFile` became identical to `FromFileUncached`.

I'll add an `[Obsolete]` attribute to the `FromFileUncached` method since it will make it more obvious inside the IDE, i.e. without reading the documentation.

> Can somebody please make clear what is the correct way to:

`FromFile[Uncached]` does not cache, `FromBundle` does.

Comment: Thanks for making this clear but why am I seeing an immense grow in "Memory Tag 70" if FromFile() is not caching and this memory is used for cached image data (as you commented on another bug)?

Comment: The above was based on documentation **This method does not cache the image object.** from http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html but it would not be the first time to find this incomplete/false :( Could you try making a small repro case and attach it to a bug report so we can look into it. Thanks

Comment: It also seems to work for others (ObjC) http://www.jorambarrez.be/blog/2012/04/19/ios-imagenamed-vs-imagewithcontentsoffile/